# How can I implement a swipe to change date in a watchOS app?

Tags: swiftui, gesture, watchos

I have a view that looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var list: [listEntry] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(list, id: \.title) { time in
                        HStack {
                            if !time.isTime {
                                Spacer()
                                Text(time.title)
                                Spacer()
                            } else {
                                Text(time.title)
                                Spacer()
                                Text(dateFormatter.string(from: time.time!))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        userChosenDate = userChosenDate.addingTimeInterval(-86400)
                        syncCalendarDates()
                        list = updateList()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        userChosenDate = userChosenDate.addingTimeInterval(86400)
                        syncCalendarDates()
                        list = updateList()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }.navigationTitle("Simple app")
        }
        .onAppear {
            getCalendarWithLocation { complexCalendar in
                // Once the complex calendar is obtained,
                // update the list using the data obtained
                calendar = complexCalendar
                list = updateList()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, there are two buttons that are at the end of the list which change the date and it causes the list to be updated. However, I would like to replace the buttons with a swipe gesture. Is this even currently possible?